# Understanting file distribution and partitioning in HDFS when using Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs, bigdata

On the one hand, in HDFS docs they say:

> HDFS is designed to support very large files. Applications that are
>   compatible with HDFS are those that deal with large data sets. These
>   applications write their data only once but they read it one or more
>   times and require these reads to be satisfied at streaming speeds.
>   HDFS supports write-once-read-many semantics on files. A typical block
>   size used by HDFS is 64 MB. Thus, an HDFS file is chopped up into 64
>   MB chunks, and if possible, each chunk will reside on a different
>   DataNode.

Meaning every file will be splitted between nodes.

On the other hand, when I use Hive or Spark SQL, I manage the partitions in such a way that there is a folder for each partition, and all the files inside belong to this partition. For example:

```
/Sales
   /country=Spain
      /city=Barcelona
         /2019-08-28.parquet
         /2019-08-27.parquet
      /city=Madrid
         /2019-08-28.parquet
         /2019-08-27.parquet
```

Let's say that each file's size is 1GB and the HDFS block size is 128 MB.

So I am confused. I don't understand if `city=Barcelonav/2019-08-28.parquet` is saved on only one node as a whole (even together with `city=Barcelona/2019-08-27.parquet`), or each file is distributed between 8 nodes.

If each file is distributed, then what is the benefit of the partitions?

If the data is distributed according to the partitions I define, how does HDFS know to do that? Does it look for folders with a name in the form of `key=value` and make sure they will be saved intact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused between "how HDFS stores the files that we dump into it" and "how Hive/Spark creates different directories in case of partitioning".

Let me try to provide you a perspective.
HDFS works as you have mentioned.
HDFS breaks up the files into `n` number of blocks depending upon the block size and the size of the file to be stored. The metadata (directories, permissions, etc..) is an abstraction in a sense that the file (`2019-08-27.parquet`) that you see as one is indeed distributed among nodes. Namenode maintains the metadata.

However, when we `partition` it creates different directories on HDFS. This ultimately helps when you want to query the data with conditions on the partitioned column. Only relevant directories are searched for the requested data. If you go ahead and query on your partitioned data and write an `explain` to have a look at the logical plan, you can notice the `Partition Filters` while `FileScan` phase.

The partitioned data is still stored on HDFS in the same way that you mentioned.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So HDFS blocks are naturally abstracted, while parquet partitions require different folders under the hood?

Comment: Everything put on HDFS is managed the same way, as far as I understand. Different folders are created only when you create partition on certain columns. These directories are maintained in a similar manner as a normal HDFS directory created using `hdfs dfs -mkdr`

Comment: Everything you see in HDFS is an abstraction, each file is really broken into blocks equal to the block size as @VihitShah explained. Partitioning in hive however involves separating the data into separate files. Each of these separate .parquet files contain a partition of your tables data, and then that file is further chopped into blocks and distributed across the nodes, just like every other HDFS file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand what caused the confusion for me: I'm coming from Cassandra world, in which partitions are intentionally saved stored on one node (except replicas) because you usually want to find a specific row and avoid accessing many nodes in order to return results in real time. But Hadoop/Hive/Spark are more for analytics in which you want to take advantage of all CPUs you have in your cluster, so it's actually better to distribute each partition in all nodes rather than storing it intact on one node (+ replicas).